# how to modify just protocol of url in a iframe tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, https

I need to use jquery to change "http" protocol of youtube video loaded through iframes tags for a "https" protocol.

here is the code I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var protocol = "http";
    var url = $('body').find('iframe').attr('src');
    if (protocol.test(url)) { // if we find http in src frame's atribute
        //then I replace just that part, for "https"
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: my guess is that is going to be too late to get around the https/http warning. (Guessing why you are doing this)

Comment: So match http: and replace it. Basic reg exp.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to test to see if `http://` is contained in the iframe source URL. If it is contained in the source URL, then replace `http://` with `https://` and set the new `src` URL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var iframe = $('body').find('iframe');
    var url = iframe.attr('src');
    if (url.includes("http://")) {
        iframe.attr('src', url.replace("http://", "https://")); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to automatically replace `http://` directly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var iframe = $('body').find('iframe');
    var url = iframe.attr('src');
    url = url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
    iframe.attr('src',url);
});
```